# Return index numbers in R where object lengths are not multiples

Tags: r

I have a vector like so:

```r
foo = c("A", "B", "C", "D")
```

And I want a vector of selected index numbers, which I imagined I could do like so:

```r
which(foo == c("A", "B", "D"))
```

But apparently this only works if the lengths of the two vectors are multiples, as otherwise you get an incomplete result followed by a warning message:

> "longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length".

So how do I get what I'm after, which is "1 2 4"?

Comment: Replace `==` by `%in%`.

Answer (score 2):

Use `match`:

```
match(c('A', 'B', 'C'), foo)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `%in%` is one option here:

```r
foo <- c("A", "B", "C", "D")
x <- c("A", "B", "D")
c(1:4)[foo %in% x]    # [1] 1 2 4
```

The quantity `foo %in% x` returns a logical vector which can then be used to subset the indices you want to see.

Comment: No need for `c`, and this seems like a very convoluted way of calling `match`. ;-)

Comment: @KonradRudolph `match` ?!  Never heard of it `:-)`